# Are there archaeological sites of Drusus‘ campaign 9 BC?

Tags: roman-empire

The Roman commander [Nero Claudius Drusus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero_Claudius_Drusus) reached the river Elbe in 9 BC.

Are there any archaeological sites or finds of this Roman campaign deep into Germania?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drususstein?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 9):

There are excavations of a Roman camp in [Hedemünden](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6merlager_Hedem%C3%BCnden) that are thought to belong into this time frame. This is located well east of the Rhine, but not *that* close to the Elbe river. Some other camps from the same set of campaigns, but further to the west or southwest, are at [Rödgen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6merlager_R%C3%B6dgen) and [Oberaden](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6merlager_Oberaden).

Another site quite to the east, but from slightly later according to coins found, is [Wilkenburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6misches_Marschlager_von_Wilkenburg) near Hanover. Some maps on WP put the Wilkenburg site into the conext of Varus' campaign in 9 AD, but the German wikipedia article puts it some years earlier.

The settlement (as opposed to camp) at [Waldgirmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldgirmes_Forum) site also belongs into roughly this timeframe.

The sites at the [Harzhorn](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harzhornereignis) and at [Hachelbich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6misches_Marschlager_bei_Hachelbich) are even further to the east, but thought to belong to much later campaigns.

Comment: Thanks. I guess Hedemünden is the only place with a fitting time frame and location. Finds from more eastern areas would be interesting.

Comment: Even further away (north of Frankfurt/Main), but maybe of interest: [Römerkastell Saalburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kastell_Saalburg), Artical: *Archaeologists are recreating Roman underfloor heating*: [Römerkastell Saalburg: Archäologen bauen römische Fußbodenheizung nach](https://www.hessenschau.de/kultur/roemerkastell-saalburg-archaeologen-bauen-roemische-fussbodenheizung-nach,experimentelle-archaeologie-saalburg-100.html)

Comment: @lejonet: See updated answer. I am actually not so familiar with this topic and I think there may be even more camps from these campaigns.